# Update SVM classifier with new data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, scikits

I trained a SVM classifier in Python using

```
clf = sklearn.svm.NuSVC(nu=0.05, probability=True, kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(points, classes)
```

And that works great for predictions.
Now I want to update the classifiers parameters.
Few points change classifications (from positive number to zero), and a few are added. Few means 50 of 10000 or more.

I thought it would be smart to nevertheless hint the SVM classifier to start at the previous parameters, which should be very close to the best solution. I have the problem that sometimes, the classifier is randomly very poor (fitting failed I presume).
Is there a way to do so in scikit-learn or libsvm?

Comment: This seems related but has no resolution: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30834/is-it-possible-to-append-training-data-to-existing-svm-models

Answer (score 5):

`NuSVC` does not offer incremental/online learning. To do that in scikit-learn, you need `SGDClassifier`. That fits a linear model, but you can get an approximation to the RBF kernel with the [`kernel_approximations`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html) module (see also [its author's blog](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.nl/2012/12/kernel-approximations-for-efficient.html)).

If you want a true online kernel learner, check out [LASVM](http://leon.bottou.org/projects/lasvm).